# Combine two query results horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have a table `scott2` from which I run two queries from.

The first query is:

```
SELECT rateid, sysuserid, appraiserid, category, rate FROM `scott2` WHERE sysuserid = appraiserid and sysuserid = '20' group by category order by category;
```

which results to:

[image]

The second is:

```
SELECT rateid, sysuserid, appraiserid, category, sum(rate) FROM `scott2` WHERE sysuserid != appraiserid and sysuserid = '20' group by category order by category asc;
```

which results to:

[image]

I want to combine the results to below format. I want the `sumrate` column from query 2 adjacent to `rate` column from query 1.

> **SYSUSERID | CATEGORY | RATE | SUMRATE**

I have tried with this subquery but to no avail.

```
SELECT sysuserid, category, 
(SELECT rate FROM `scott2` WHERE sysuserid = appraiserid and sysuserid = '20' group by category order by category asc) as 'rate',
(select sum(rate) from scott2 where sysuserid != appraiserid and sysuserid = '20' group by category order by category asc) as 'sumrate'
from scott2
group by category
order by category asc;
```

It errors:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: What's your expect result? What's the mean about `I want the sumrate column from query 2 adjacent to rate column from query 1.`

Comment: Does this table have any primary key?

Comment: @PraveenS, yes, the `rateid`

Comment: @D-Shih, I want the resulting table to have the columns: `SYSUSERID | CATEGORY | RATE | SUMRATE`

Comment: @xjshiya You need the "sumrate" result as total sum rate of Same type Category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main query you did not mantion "sysuserid = 20" in where and you are using "sysuserid = '20'"  that is not valid. Also when you are using group by category in main query you should mantion category in where condition od sub query.

To limit subquery secord with only one result, you can use limit. Although limit is not valid. You should validate unique result for combination of "sysuserid"+"category" logically.

You can try below query.

```
SELECT sysuserid, category, 
(SELECT sc_i.rate FROM `scott2` as sc_i WHERE sc_i.sysuserid = sc_i.appraiserid and sc_i.sysuserid = sc.sysuserid and sc_i.category = sc.category limit 1) as 'rate',
(SELECT sc_i.rate FROM `scott2` as sc_i WHERE sc_i.sysuserid <> sc_i.appraiserid and sc_i.sysuserid = sc.sysuserid and sc_i.category = sc.category limit 1) as 'sumrate'
from scott2 as sc
where sysuserid = 20
group by sysuserid, category
order by category asc;
```

Comment: You have forgotten the `sum` but this worked beautifully. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
SELECT t1.sysuserid, t1.category, t1.rate , 
    (select sum(rate) from scott2 t2 where t2.category = t1.category AND sysuserid != appraiserid and sysuserid = '20' group by category) as sumrate

from scott2 t1
group by t1.category
order by t1.category asc;
```